# Trying to get Wordpress ACF to include a video either from YouTube or Vimeo but instead I am getting a 500 error

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Here is my code when I don't have the if statement the page will load properly however as soon as I add the if statement it goes to a 500 error page.

Yes I know I am missing the Vimeo if statement however that shouldn't matter at this point.

```
<?php
  $youtube = get_field('youtube1');
  $vimeo = get_field('vimeo1');

  if ($youtube) {
    echo '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . the_field('youtube1') . '"></iframe>'
  }
?>
```

Edit: Clarification, when I echo out the iframe without the if statement it works. However, when I try to say if ($youtube) echo iframe, it breaks.

I should be echoing the variable and not the_field('youtube1') here is my updated code. I am still getting the 500 error.

```
<?php
  $youtube = get_field('youtube1');
  $vimeo = get_field('vimeo1');

  if ($youtube) {
    echo '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $youtube . '"></iframe>'
  }
?>
```

semicolons are important in php... oops here is the updated code however even when the ACF is blank on the page it is still echoing an iframe video with no video ID so it's just a broken video.

```
<?php
  $youtube = get_field('youtube1');
  $vimeo = get_field('vimeo1');

  if ('' !== strval($youtube)) {
    echo '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $youtube1 . '"></iframe>';
  }
?>
```

edit edit: False alarm I believe I had something cached. The above code is the correct code and seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to echo something in your echo statement. The function `the_field()` echoes the value of the field. You should either use `get_field()` or just use the 
 `$youtube` variable.

Here is the updated code:

```
<?php
    $youtube = get_field('youtube1');
    $vimeo = get_field('vimeo1');

    if ('' !== strval($youtube)) {
        echo '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $youtube . '"></iframe>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I actually meant to change it to $youtube, however, this is still giving me a 500 error. I'll update my code above to reflect this change because you are right it should be $youtube and not the_field('youtube1')

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace and are you sure, that the 500 error is coming from this code? Maybe a stupid question, but is ACF activated?

Comment: I am not sure what a stack trace is... And yes ACF is activated because I am using it in a lot of places. Also the 500 error is almost certainly coming from this code because as soon as I remove the if ($youtube) { } but leave the echo portion it works.

Comment: What does `$youtube` contain after `$youtube = get_field('youtube1')`? Could you please provide the output of `var_dump($youtube)`?

Comment: string(11) "CduA0TULnow" edit: and now everyone knows my placeholder video is totally Britany Spears.

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer. The echo statement was missing a semicolon at the end and I've also created a check, that the content of the variable is not an empty string.

Comment: Duh! I'm used to javascript where the semicolon isn't needed however in PHP it is needed. One problem with the above code my iframe is still being echoed even when get_field('youtube1') is blank on the WordPress page. I'll update my code in the question.

Comment: Actually I may have had something cached because I believe it is working properly. It isn't spitting out my ACF in the if statment echo however that I may be able to figure out myself. And at this point I think it's a new question so you answered the initial question thank you!

Comment: Like I said this is probably a new question but I found the issue quickly and wanted to know if you knew why. When I put the variable into the echo statment it doesn't actually pull the data from $youtube1 however if I do get_field('youtube1') it does work. So it's not a big deal I will just do get_field() instead of the variable.

Comment: You are echoing `$youtube1` instead of `$youtube`. youtube1 is the name of your ACF field, whereas the variable is named `$youtube`.